# Is there any hardware decoding or encoding when reading video stream byte in pyav python?

Tags: python, encoding, video-streaming, decoding, pyav

I have a python scripts for reading video bytes using pyav package as below code. when I use this code I figured out that reading that video byte for a long stream using a lot amount of CPU RAM and makes all cores busy(High CPU usage). But in my project I want to process them in realtime with lower CPU usage, so I want to know is there any hardware encoding or hardware decoding for reading stream in pyav(i.e GPU based instead of CPU based)

```py
    def _get_video_stream_info(self, video_bytes):
        stream_options = [{'codec': 'h264'}]

        self.container = av.open(video_bytes, stream_options=stream_options)

        video_stream = [s for s in self.container.streams if s.type == "video"][0]

        fps = int(video_stream.average_rate)
        total_frames = video_stream.frames
        logger.info(f'[INFO] FPS video straem = {fps}')
        logger.info(f'[INFO] Total frames video straem = {total_frames}')

        num_split_frames = self.duration_split * fps

        packet_list = []
        for packet in self.container.demux(video_stream):
            packet_list.append(packet)

        return packet_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt this example to your fits, you need to create a Codec context,below with Nvidia cuda

```
import av

video = av.open(VIDEO_FILE_PATH)
target_stream = video.streams.video[0]
ctx = av.Codec('h264_cuvid', 'r').create()
for packet in 
    video.demux(target_stream):
    for frame in ctx.decode(packet):
        print(frame)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christoph for replying. I tried this solution but I faced an error for av package:                
                           
```python          
ctx = av.Codec('h264_cuvid', 'r').create()                                 

  File "av/codec/codec.pyx", line 184, in av.codec.codec.Codec.__cinit__
  File "av/codec/codec.pyx", line 193, in av.codec.codec.Codec._init
av.codec.codec.UnknownCodecError: h264_cuvid```

Comment: OK it works on my machine with valid ffmpeg builds looks u need to investigate why this happen maybe rebuild pyav from source help

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, I installed av by `pip install av`            
   my versions are              
```av version = 9.0.2
,
ffmpeg version 7:3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2```    I would be appreciated, if you can send any link to build av from a correct source

Comment: Try this ctx = av.CodecContext.create('h264_cuvid', 'r')

Comment: Just Look into the github repo there are the build instructions :)

Comment: I also tried that solution but none of can not recognize `h264_cuvid`

Comment: I had to add this: `ctx.extradata = target_stream.codec_context.extradata`